# Css Shape with before and after

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to do this shape with css3:

[image: Desired Example]

Is it possible with css3 or good idea to keep it as a background image. If I make it with background images, is there any problem with making it responsive?

I tried with before and after elements, but couldn't get it working:

```css
#shape {
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-top: 70px solid #ffde00;
  border-right: 70px solid #ffde00;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #ffde00;
}
#shape2 {
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-top: 70px solid #ffde00;
  border-right: 70px solid #ffde00;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #ffde00;
  position: relative;
}
#shape2 h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffde00;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 90px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
</br>
<div id="shape2"></div>
<div class="title">
  <h2> New Title ,</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define - _"but this not works"_. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: hi @chipChocolate.py 
i want use this images with css.But also confused, what is the best solutions for this kind of issue--: using css shape or background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of how to do this shape with CSS3:

```css
 #shape {
        border-left: 70px solid transparent;
        border-top: 70px solid #ffde00;
        border-right: 70px solid #ffde00;
        border-bottom: 70px solid #ffde00; 
      }
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks .I am trying to do this from last night. but how easily you solve this :) 
So, can you suggest me , should i work with css or taking background image for this kind of shape.

Comment: I think that it depends of what you really want to do. In same cases is more easy to do with CSS other with background image.

Comment: Thanks . i have a title on top of this shape. and if i take h2 tag in between shape id, its display white background . 
So, is it possible to display a title on top of this shape..?
Thanks again